# SQL - Como contar dias trabalhados

Tags: sql

A tabela ACESSOBROA_NOVO registra o acesso dos funcionários da empresa sempre que eles passam por uma catraca.

Preciso fazer uma query nesta tabela que liste o nome dos funcionários e conte os dias trabalhados num período, por exemplo, de 5 dias.

Como nesta tabela estão registrados todas as vezes que ele entrou e saiu da empresa num mesmo dia a seguinte query não funciona:

```
SELECT distinct NOME_FUN, EMPRESA,count(DATAR) as 'dias trabalhdos' 
  FROM [RDO].[dbo].[ACESSOBROA_NOVO]
  where CC=11396 and DATAR between '2015-09-21' and '2015-09-21'
  group by NOME_FUN, empresa
```

Pois como preciso somente verificar se o funcionário esteve presente nos dias solicitados e não contar quantas vezes ele passou na catraca.

Segue uma amostra da tabela:

[image: Amostra da tabela]

Comment: tentou usar COUNT(DISTINCT DATAR) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que colocando **DISTINCT** no **COUNT**, você vai ter o resultado esperado:

```
SELECT distinct NOME_FUN, EMPRESA,count(DISTINCT DATAR) as 'dias trabalhdos' 
  FROM [RDO].[dbo].[ACESSOBROA_NOVO]
  where CC=11396 and DATAR between '2015-09-21' and '2015-09-21'
  group by NOME_FUN, empresa
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp